# Reactable filterable doesn't make input box

Tags: reactjs

Using `Reactable` I've produced a table with pagination which works nicely.

I want to add filtering.

Current table:

```
<ReactTable
    className='-striped -highlight'
    data={data}
    columns={columns}
    defaultPageSize={20}
/>
```

This works well.

According to the docs [on Github](https://github.com/glittershark/reactable#filtering), I should simply add `filterable` to the table -- . `If the filterable property is provided, then an input box with class reactable-filter-input will be prepended to the thead of the table.`

```
<ReactTable
            className='-striped -highlight'
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
            defaultPageSize={20}
            filterable={['Time', 'Type']}
/>
```

However, no input box appears. Am I missing a step? `Time` and `Type` are my two only columns. And the table is rendered and shown properly with the `data`.

Sample code:

```
const ReactTable = require('react-table').default;
// .... 

render () {

    let data = this.props.data;

    const columns = [{
        header: 'Time',
        accessor: 'time'
    }, {
        header: 'Type',
        accessor: 'type',
    }];

    let tableArr = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tableArr.push({
                time: epochToDateTime(data[i].ts),
                type : data[i].type,
            });
    }

    return (
        <div style={{width: "100%"}}>
                    <ReactTable className='-striped -highlight'
                                data={tableArr}
                                columns={columns}
                                defaultPageSize={this.pageSize}
                                filterable={['Time']}/>
         </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I dn think so. I created a simple fiddle here and it looks ok. https://jsfiddle.net/marudhupandiyang/5858hag3/3/

Comment: Strange. I thought it might be hidden somewhere behind another element, but i can't see it in my developer tools either.

Comment: Added a sample, even with just this, the input element doesn't appear :-/

Comment: What is the data type returned by `epochToDateTime`. Try pushing a random string to `time` in `tableArr` and check if filter appears.

Comment: It just takes epoch and converts it to a time + date. I tried your suggestion but still no filter. I even tried with "type" which is a string but also doesnt work